# vector calculus - line in vector form

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I'm really confused in the part of vector calculus by [the book by Michael Corral](https://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi05cfy94zRAhVFO48KHX9YBdcQFggYMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mecmath.net%2Fcalc3book.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHaZioCHqqCO924EPbzoMQrUS2fIg).
In the part of the "Line through a point and parallel to a plane", parametric representation of a line L through a point P parallel to a vector **v**, has been described.
[image]

Theorem 1.16 given in the book(p.g. 31) states that it can be obtained by the formula:
                **r** + t**v**, where t is the parameter,
The question down in page 32, example 1.19, tells us to write the line L, through the point P and parallel to the vector v, in the vector form. This is solutioned only by the above formula.

But, as you can see in the diagram I have presentd above, which is much similar to the book, is the vector from the origin to Q. So, how is the vector even parallel, and *even* passing through the point P?

Comment: It could very well be a misprint (typo) in the typesetting. Perhaps the typo occurs here on the diagram, or in the exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the main confusions in writing a line in vector form is to determine what $\vec{r}(t)=\vec{r}+t\vec{v}$ actually is and how it describes a line.

For each $t_0$, $\vec{r}(t_0)$ is a vector starting at the origin whose endpoint is on the desired line.  You don't get a vector which points in the same direction as the line, but a vector ending on a line.  For different $t$-values, the endpoint of the vector $\vec{r}(t)$ gives different points along the line.

On the other hand, the vector $\vec{v}=\vec{PQ}$ is parallel to the given line (even though when this vector starts at the origin, it doesn't intersect the given line).

The geometric meaning of the equation $\vec{r}(t)=\vec{r}+t\vec{v}$ is as follows:  $\vec{r}$ is a vector from the origin to the line and $\vec{v}$ is a vector parallel to the desired line.  $\vec{r}$ is an arrow from the origin to a point on the line.  Then $t\vec{v}$ moves you from the endpoint of $\vec{r}$ in the direction of $\vec{v}$, which is parallel to the line.  Since we're starting on the line after moving $\vec{r}$, this means that we're adding a vector/segment along the line.

I think of this as "giving directions", from the origin to get to a desired point on the line, walk to any point on the line (this is $\vec{r}$) and then walk in the direction of the line the desired distance (since $\vec{v}$ points in the direction of the line, $t\vec{v}$ scales the vector until it is the correct distance).  The result are directions from the origin to a point on the line.  Therefore, the resulting vector is not parallel to the line, but it starts at the origin and ends on the line.

Comment: meaning it's the line that we're more considerate about rather than the vector

Comment: Meaning that we're representing the desired line in a way that can be confusing because the geometry doesn't necessarily align with our first idea of what should be happening.

Answer (score 1):

The key to using vectors to represent a line not through the origin
is the *correspondence between points and vectors* described on
page 5 of your book.
Namely, since a vector can be described by three coordinates
$x,y,z$ and a point also can be described by three coordinates $x,y,z,$
we use the vector with coordinates $1,2,17$ (for example) as a
way to identify the point with coordinates $1,2,17.$

So when the book says that $\mathbf r + t \mathbf v$ is on the
line parallel to $\mathbf v$ through the point $P,$
it does not mean that the entire arrow labeled $\mathbf r + t \mathbf v$
in your figure is on that line.
It means only that when you draw the vector $\mathbf r + t \mathbf v$
so that its tail (starting point) is at the origin of your
coordinate system, the *tip* (ending point) of the vector is on
the desired line.

So another way to think about the vector formula $\mathbf r + t \mathbf v$
is that you take the three coordinates of the point $P$
and use them as the coordinates of a vector $\mathbf r.$
When you do this, the vector $\mathbf r$ gives the distance and
(if needed) the direction from the origin $(0,0,0)$ to the point $P.$
You take the vector $\mathbf v$ and multiply it by $t,$
that is, you multiply each of its coordinates by $t,$
to get a vector $t \mathbf v,$
and then you add the two vectors $\mathbf r$ and $t \mathbf v$
coordinate by coordinate to get the vector $\mathbf r + t \mathbf v.$
The vector $\mathbf r + t \mathbf v$ is described by three coordinates
which are also the three coordinates of a point on the desired line.

In short, *don't look at the arrow,* look only at the end point.

---

**Aside:**
I have a small quibble with the way this book describes vectors.
When the book defines *vector,* it says
a vector is a directed line segment.
This implies that a vector has six coordinates: the three coordinates
of its starting point and the three coordinates of its ending point.
And yet somehow the vector starting at $(1,1,2)$ and ending at $(4,5,7)$
is said to be "equal" to the vector starting at
$(0,0,0)$ and ending at $(3,4,5).$
I would rather say that a vector is only the displacement
(distance and direction)
from one point to another, which is in fact exactly the same for both
sets of points: $3$ units in the positive $x$ direction,
$4$ units in the positive $y$ direction, and $5$ units in the
positive $z$ direction will take you from $(1,1,2)$ to $(4,5,7)$
just as surely as it will take you from $(0,0,0)$ to $(3,4,5).$

According to my preferred definition, the arrow labeled
$\mathbf r + t \mathbf v$ in your figure
is not "the" vector $\mathbf r + t \mathbf v$;
it is not even a vector equal to $\mathbf r + t \mathbf v.$
Instead, it shows how the vector $\mathbf r + t \mathbf v$
relates the origin of coordinates to a point on the desired line:
if you start at the origin, and use the vector $\mathbf r + t \mathbf v$
to determine how far to travel in what direction,
you will get to a point on the line.

Comment: from the "Aside" part, "it is not even a vector equal to r + tv"? Please explain this part to me, how is it not a vector equal to r + tv? What would the triangle law suggest then?

Comment: @lind I simply meant that an arrow on a diagram is not a vector, in my preferred version of vector calculus. An arrow has a specific starting point and a specific ending point. A vector does not, so the arrow cannot be a vector. This particular arrow _does_ have the same "shape" as the vector r+tv, and that is how I interpret it when an arrow in a figure is labeled with the name of a vector. The technical difference between the vector and the arrow may or may not be relevant to you, however, which is why it's only an "aside."

Comment: I see, your point is the physical preciseness of the vectors

Comment: I would like to hear your opinion on this:  How would you informally interpret the dot product of two vectors? By informal interpretation I mean something that is physically sensible; example: 10m bridge is divided by 2 equals to 5(mathematically), but 5 peices of bridge each of 2m a peice(sensibly),? I hope I put it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The vector equation is:
$$
\vec x=\vec p +t \vec v \qquad t \in \mathbb{R}
$$
that is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_0\\y_0\\z_0
\end{pmatrix}+t
\begin{pmatrix}
v_x\\v_y\\v_z
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and, for $t=0$, ve have $\vec x=(x_0,y_0,z_0)^T=\vec p$. For other values of $t$ we have the other points on the line.

Comment: I don't well understand the symbols in your figure, but $\vec p$ is your vector from the origin to the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

Comment: Well, the points in the line can be obtained, but, p vector + t . v vector, is a vector, isn't this vector supposed to be parallel to v vector, but as you can see in the figure above it's not the case

Comment: $\vec x$ is a vector that point to a line  and **this line** ( not the vector $\vec x$) is parallel to the vector$\vec v$.

Comment: I got it, thanks!